# Swift Error - Use of undeclared type 'cell' - Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Quite new to programming in Swift, what is the reason to my error and how can I fix it? Many thanks.

```
import UIKit
import Photos


class PhotosViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate

{

    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!


    var imagesArray = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myCollectionView.delegate = self
        myCollectionView.dataSource = self

    }

    @IBAction func addPhoto(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let picker:UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!

        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell


        cell.configurecell(imagesArray[indexPath.row])

        return cell

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return imagesArray.count

    }



    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let pickedimage = (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage){
            imagesArray = [pickedimage,pickedimage,pickedimage]//Will store three selected images in your array
            myCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: `as! cell` - this part is problematic, you need a type name to cast to. `cell` is a variable name.

Comment: @Cristik - Cheers for the quick response. Sorry as I'm new to swift not sure what you mean - could you provide some detail to what I can do to fix?

Comment: have you made a custom class for the tableViewCell?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set an Identifier in your Attributes inspector.

1. click on the entire cell in your storyboard.
2. Select Attributes inspector
3. Provide a identifier name (e.g. identifier= cell)

   For more clarification-
   First Image
   [image]
   Second Image
   [image]

Comment: Cheers for the quick response! I have already done that, the error is with the as! cell part

Comment: cast as! yourViewController class name . Like - as! collectionViewCell(your storyBoard class name) @ConnorBerry

Answer (score 2):

1. If you have defined your custom `UICollectionViewCell` class with class name: `MyCell`, then use that in this line:

> ```
>     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell
> ```

2. Please make sure that you have chosen the same class name for the cell in your storyboard (By clicking on the cell object and choose your class name in `Custom Class` field. (see image below)

[image: select custom class]

3. Also make sure that you are using the same `Cell Identifier` as you have entered in your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Your_Cell_Class_Name
        cell.configurecell(imagesArray[indexPath.row])
        return cell
}
```

In Your cellForItemAt Method just replace `as! cell` with `Your_Cell_Class_Name` As there is no class named cell in your code.

**Happy Coding**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better way of casting the collection view cell to your custom class type, without "force casting" (when you use `as!`):

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let _cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", for: indexPath)
    guard let cell = _cell as? CollectionViewCell else { return _cell } // Replace "CollectionViewCell" with your custom class name
    cell.configurecell(imagesArray[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

As you can see, I'm using `as?` instead of `as!` to cast the cell to type `CollectionViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

1- You have to make sure that the cell is connected to the same class you are using.

2- Make sure that you declared the `cellIdentifier` for the cell.

3- If you created this cell with `.xib` file then you need to declare it first in the `viewDidLoad()` by writing the below line:

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "cell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```